# Cloudwatch agent with role instead access and secret key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I got this deployment from the internet and tested it with great result. My question is, are there config parameters that i can use to pass a role ARN instead of access key and secret key? I tried passing a role ARN in various forms inside aws-credentials. But it was to no avail.

```
---
# Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cwagent-prometheus
  namespace: amazon-cloudwatch
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cwagent-prometheus
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cwagent-prometheus
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: cloudwatch-agent
          image: amazon/cloudwatch-agent:1.247348.0b251302
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: CI_VERSION
              value: "k8s/1.3.8"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: prometheus-cwagentconfig
              mountPath: /etc/cwagentconfig
            - name: prometheus-config
              mountPath: /etc/prometheusconfig
            - name: aws-credentials
              mountPath: /root/.aws
      volumes:
        - name: prometheus-cwagentconfig
          configMap:
            name: prometheus-cwagentconfig
        - name: prometheus-config
          configMap:
            name: prometheus-config
        - name: aws-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: aws-credentials
      serviceAccountName: cwagent-prometheus
```

The typical working solution is to provide aws-credentials with the format:

```
[AmazonCloudWatchAgent]
aws_access_key_id = $AWS_ID
aws_secret_access_key = $AWS_KEY
```

For instance, I tried changing it to:

```
[AmazonCloudWatchAgent]
role_arn = $ROLE_ARN
```

With this solution, the cloudwatch agent will complain about not finding aws_access_key_id in the credentials.

Comment: I think the only way you can use a role is if the EC2 instance itself as a role attached to it, in which case you don't need to do anything

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue and still not resolved yet.

- [Use IAM Roles for Service Accounts](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/issues/308) issue on [amazon-cloudwatch-agent](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent)
- [aws-helm-eks-charts](https://github.com/aws/eks-charts/issues/517) issue